# Error building MikTeX format "csplain"

Tags: miktex, csplain

I am trying to build new MikTeX format "csplain". The reason is that after unpacking MikTeX portable csplain is not enabled by default. The sequence of steps can be seen in following screenshots:

1.

[image]

2. Unchecked option "Exclude this format when updating all format files".

[image]

3. Clicked on "Build" button.

[image]

4. Received following error message:

[image]

5. Clicked on "Áno" (means Yes in english language):

[image]

This is output of command "pdftex -ini -enable-enctex csplain-utf8.ini" recommended by Ulrike for better diagnostics of problem:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (INITEX)
 encTeX v. Jun. 2004, reencoding enabled.
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csplain-utf8.ini
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csplain.ini
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csfonts.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\plain\base\plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\hyphen\hyphen.tex))
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csfontsm.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\il2code.tex
Font encoding set to ISO-8859-2.)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\hyphen.lan
Loading US English hyphenation patterns in ASCII encoding, \enPatt=0 (en).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\hyphen.ex
Enhyphex.tex English exception words.)
Loading Czech hyphenation patterns in ISO-8859-2 encoding, \csILtwo=5 (cs).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\czhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\hyphen\czhyphen.ex)
Loading Slovak hyphenation patterns in ISO-8859-2 encoding, \skILtwo=6 (sk).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.ex)
Loading Czech hyphenation patterns in Cork encoding, \csCork=15 (cs).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\t1code.tex
Font encoding set to Cork.)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\czhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\hyphen\czhyphen.ex)
Loading Slovak hyphenation patterns in Cork encoding, \skCork=16 (sk).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\t1code.tex
Font encoding set to Cork.)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.ex)
5 patterns preloaded: \enPatt =0 \csILtwo =5 \skILtwo =6 \csCork =15 \skCork =1
6  Defaults: \language=0, \cmaccents, \nonfrenchspacing,
ISO-8859-2 font encoding)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\plaina4.tex
\hsize=159.2 mm \vsize=239.2 mm)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csenc-u.tex
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\enctex\utf8unkn.tex)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.116 ...in=1 \mubyteout=3 \mubytelog=1 \xprncodes
                                                  =0
```

And this is full output of build command after doing all the things recommended by Ulrike:

```
Creating the csplain format file...
Running miktex-pdftex.exe...
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9) (INITEX)
entering extended mode
 encTeX v. Jun. 2004, reencoding enabled.
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csplain-utf8.ini
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csplain.ini
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csfonts.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\plain\base\plain.tex
Preloading the plain format: codes, registers, parameters, fonts, more fonts,
macros, math definitions, output routines, hyphenation
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\hyphen\hyphen.tex))
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csfontsm.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\il2code.tex
Font encoding set to ISO-8859-2.)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\hyphen.lan
eTeX's \savinghyphcodes detected - \lccode settings per pattern are saved.
Loading US English hyphenation patterns in ASCII encoding, \enPatt=0 (en).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\hyphen.ex
Enhyphex.tex English exception words.)
Loading Czech hyphenation patterns in ISO-8859-2 encoding, \csILtwo=5 (cs).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\czhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\czhyphen.ex)
Loading Slovak hyphenation patterns in ISO-8859-2 encoding, \skILtwo=6 (sk).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.ex)
Loading Czech hyphenation patterns in Cork encoding, \csCork=15 (cs).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\t1code.tex
Font encoding set to Cork.)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\czhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\czhyphen.ex)
Loading Slovak hyphenation patterns in Cork encoding, \skCork=16 (sk).
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\t1code.tex
Font encoding set to Cork.)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.tex)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\skhyphen.ex)
5 patterns preloaded: \enPatt =0 \csILtwo =5 \skILtwo =6 \csCork =15 \skCork =1
6  Defaults: \language=0, \cmaccents, \nonfrenchspacing,
ISO-8859-2 font encoding)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\plaina4.tex
\hsize=159.2 mm \vsize=239.2 mm)
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csenc-u.tex
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\enctex\utf8unkn.tex)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.116 ...in=1 \mubyteout=3 \mubytelog=1 \xprncodes
                                                  =0
No pages of output.
Transcript written on csplain-utf8.log.
miktex-makefmt: miktex-pdftex.exe failed on csplain-utf8.ini.
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
initexmf.EXE: Data: f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\miktex\bin\miktex-makefmt.exe
```

**P.S.**

To be more specific about my installation. I downloaded official MikTex portable package 2.9.5105 from http://miktex.org/download and unpacked it. Never used any other version of MikTex on my computer. My operating system is Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit.

**P.S. 2**

To answer more specifically to question of Petr here you see file versions of tex\generic\enctex\utf8unkn.tex file. On left side you see screenshot from MikTeX portable installation after update. On right side you see content of installation package "miktex-portable-2.9.5105.exe" (which is 7z archive).

[image]

Comment: A sorry loking at the formats.ini I see that this format needs a special argument. So try with `pdftex -ini -enable-enctex csplain-utf8.ini`

Comment: `\xprncodes` is on my system defined in the file `utf8unkn.tex` which is loaded just before the error message (at line 65). Did you check with the update manager if your system is up-to-date? Can you show the content of your version of the file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your code:

```
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\csplain\base\csenc-u.tex
(f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\enctex\utf8unkn.tex)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.116 ...in=1 \mubyteout=3 \mubytelog=1 \xprncodes
                                                  =0
```

implies that the file `f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\tex\generic\enctex\utf8unkn.tex` is read and then the Undefined control sequence occurs. But the file `utf8unkn.tex` looks like:

```
...
% \xprncodes=1 or \xprncodes=0 .. set/unset printability of 128..255 chars

\def\xprncodes=#1 {%
  \count255=128
  \loop \xprncode\count255=#1\advance\count255 by 1
  \ifnum \count255<256 \repeat
}
```

it means that the `\xprncodes` *is* defined. Very probably there is a version mishmash because the file `utf8unkn.tex` is from `enctex` package but all another files are from `csplain` package. First of all: check the contents of your `utf8unkn.tex` file (if the definition is here). If no, then the package `enctex` has version Jan 2010 or older. The definition `\xprncode` was introduced from version Oct. 2012. Now, we have the version Jul 2014. All versions are available [at CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/enctex), you can check what verion is present on your computer.

If there is version 2010 or older in MikTeX as default, than this is reason for bug reporting.

And **I am surprised** that the csplain isn't enabled by default in MikTeX. I have asked Christian Schenk to enable `csplain` and `pdfcsplain` commands/fromats (two years before now). Christian has answered me that this is done. If no, then this is another reason of bug reporting, IMHO.
*If user needs only one simple click and all is generated well then all is OK from my point of view.*

Sorry, I cannot check it because I am not (and never was) the user of MS Win.

Petr Olšák, the author of encTeX and csplain

Comment: The creation of the csplain format works fine on an up-to-date miktex. The format isn't build by default (like a lot formats) but it needs only one click to enable it. Btw: the name is Christian Schenk.

Comment: Thanks to name correction. I apologize. This is my very often mistake with this name, I don't know how.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer You write: The creation of the csplain format works fine on an up-to-date miktex. I am pleasured to read it. But I have received by email just today another bug report about csplain in mikTeX from different source. So I don't know...

Comment: My version of utf8unkn.tex was from year 2003. The solution was to right click into tray bar and choose "Update MiKTeX" option. But as Ulrike correctly pointed the formats.ini content was destroyed by clicking on "exclude" checkbox. This problem persists even after updating MiKTeX installation. So I had to restore formats.ini from original installation package miktex-portable-2.9.5105.exe which is a 7z archive.

Comment: Thank you Petr and Ulrike I would be lost without your advice.

Comment: @wipet The selection of  auto-built formats with portably MiKTeX is very small (doesn't do XeTeX/XeLaTeX/LuaTeX/LuaLaTeX, for example). Perhaps that's the reason you are getting questions?

Comment: @JosephWright No. The various mystic problems with MikTeX are reported in my inbox. The last one from yesterday: the `pdfcsplain` command generates DVI results, no PDF. And the Win users communicate using occult dialog boxes which is totally out of my understanding of computers: command lines and text oriented configuration files. So I am unable to reconstruct the problem and I am unable to help them.

Comment: @wipet Was just a suggestion :-) I guess Ulrike and I will just have to deal with the Windows users!

Comment: @truthseeker Thanks for detail explanation. Would you explain why your installation has have the file utf8unkn.tex from year 2003? Your problem isn't unique as we can see at http://pastebin.com/5ZpyRpDw Second line in the "problem" prefixed paragraph says: "chyba neznámého registru \xprncodes někde v běhu encTeXu." which means "error of unknown \xprncodes in encTeX run". This is the same as your problem.

Comment: It seems that in official installation file downloaded from miktex.org some packages are outdated. After updating the whole installation of MiKTeX the file utf8unkn.tex from 18.2.2003 was replaced with newer version from 2.11.2012.

Answer (score 2):

The format definition is wrong. You don't have a compiler selected and the input file is missing. On my (non-portable) miktex it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately list of available compilers is empty.

Comment: Hm. What with other formats? E.g. pdflatex or lualatex. Do they have a compiler?

Comment: No, none of them.

Comment: Perhaps it is this problem but for formats.ini: https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2342/. So check the content of formats.ini in miktex/config. If it looks empty try to replace it with the original one (it should be in the miktex-config-2.9 package).

Comment: Now the compilers lists are not empty but the build of csplain fails with the same reason "miktex-makefmt: Unknown engine".

Comment: Don't change the entry (by clicking on the "exclude" button), this probably destroys the formats.ini and so the entries again. Simply select csplain in the list and click on build.

Comment: Now I got further. But the build again stops with the following errors:
miktex-makefmt: miktex-pdftex.exe failed on csplain-utf8.ini.
initexmf.EXE: The operation failed for some reason.
initexmf.EXE: Data: f:\Software\_Office\MikTex\miktex\bin\miktex-makefmt.exe

Comment: That can be due to a lot of things. Open a command line in some empty test folder and try `pdftex -ini csplain-utf8.ini` to get some better error messages.